# Как можно в модели вытащить связные записи

Tags: php, phalcon

По умолчанию в модели создаётся такой метод

```
 public static function find($parameters = null)
    {
        return parent::find($parameters);
    }
```

Модель Users она в принципе связана с моделью Images
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так я получаю список всех пользователей

```
  $objects = Users::find();
            $temp    = array();
            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                $temp[] = $object;
            }

            echo json_encode($temp);
```

Чтобы вытащить изображения я должен сделать как то так

```
  $objects = Users::find();
            $temp    = array();
            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                $t      = $object->images;
                $temp[] = $object;
            }

            echo json_encode($temp);
```

**Как перенести это подтягивание в модель?**

Ответ приблизительно такой

```
[{"id":"1","name":"test1","email":"test101@mail.ru","image_id":"2","images":{"id":"2","path":"\/test2.jpg"}}]
```

Тут в комментах человеку не очень понятно было как это работает, думаю разработчики phalcon хотели чтобы я писал как то так:

```
$objects = Users::find();

                $answer = array();
                foreach ($objects as $object) {  
                    $temp = new StdClass();                  
                    $temp->id = $object->id;
                    $temp->name = $object->name;
                    $temp->email= $object->email;
                    $temp->image = $object->images;
                    $answer[] = $temp;
                }

                echo json_encode($temp);
```

Comment: Уточню: вы хотите использовать такую конструкцию `Users::find(1)->images` и получать таким образом все картинки для пользователя #1. Правильно? Из примера неясно, зачем вам, например, переменная `$t`?

Comment: @VenZell она по сути низачем, она просто для того чтобы вызвать, после этого в ответ попадает объект из модели images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собирать массив из моделей можно так:
`$users = User::find()->toArray();`
Чтобы сразу подгружать связанные модели, то можно переопределить метод `toArray()`, как показано здесь
https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4051/phalcon-include-relationships-in-json

```
public function toArray()
{
     $res = parent::toArray();
     $res['contacts'] = [];
     foreach ($this->Contacts as $contact) {
        $res['contacts'][] = $contact->toArray();
     }
     return $res;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас с symfony работаю там это на уровни entity  реализовано